# How to mutate another item in a vector, but not the vector itself, while iterating over the vector?

Tags: iterator, rust, borrow-checker

It is quite clear to me that iterating over a vector shouldn't let the loop body mutate the vector arbitrarily. This prevents iterator invalidation, which is prone to bugs.

However, not all kinds of mutation lead to iterator invalidation. See the following example:

```
let mut my_vec: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![vec![1,2], vec![3,4], vec![5,6]];
for inner in my_vec.iter_mut() {        // <- or .iter()
    // ...
    my_vec[some_index].push(inner[0]);  // <-- ERROR
}
```

Such a mutation does not invalidate the iterator of `my_vec`, however it is disallowed. It could invalidate any references to the specific elements in `my_vec[some_index]` but we do not use any such references anyway.

I know that these questions are common, and I'm not asking for an explanation. I am looking for a way to refactor this so that I can get rid of this loop. In my actual code I have a huge loop body and I can't modularize it unless I express this bit nicely.

What I have thought of so far:

1. Wrapping the vector with `Rc<RefCell<...>>`. I think this would still fail at runtime, since the `RefCell` would be borrowed by the iterator and then will fail when the loop body tries to borrow it.
2. Using a temporary vector to accumulate the future pushes, and push them after the loop ends. This is okay, but needs more allocations than pushing them on the fly.
3. Unsafe code, and messing with pointers.
4. Anything listed in the [`Iterator` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) does not help. I checked out [itertools](http://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/index.html) and it looks like it wouldn't help either.
5. Using a `while` loop and indexing instead of using an iterator making use of a reference to the outer vector. This is okay, but does not let me use iterators and adapters. I just want to get rid of this outer loop and use `my_vec.foreach(...)`.

Are there any idioms or any libraries which would let me do this nicely Unsafe functions would be okay as long as they don't expose pointers to me.

Comment: Is `some_index` constant? Or can it be predicted?

Comment: It solely depends on the specific contents of `inner` at each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap each of the inner vectors in a `RefCell`.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let my_vec : Vec<RefCell<Vec<i32>>> = vec![
        RefCell::new(vec![1,2]),
        RefCell::new(vec![3,4]),
        RefCell::new(vec![5,6])];
    for inner in my_vec.iter() {
        // ...
        let value = inner.borrow()[0];
        my_vec[some_index].borrow_mut().push(value);
    }
}
```

Note that the `value` binding here is important if you need to be able to push to the vector that `inner` refers to. `value` happens to be a type that doesn't contain references (it's `i32`), so it doesn't keep the first borrow active (it ends by the end of the statement). Then, the next statement may borrow the same vector or another vector mutably and it'll work.

If we wrote `my_vec[some_index].borrow_mut().push(inner.borrow()[0]);` instead, then both borrows would be active until the end of the statement. If both `my_vec[some_index]` and `inner` refer to the same `RefCell<Vec<i32>>`, this will panic with `RefCell<T> already mutably borrowed`.

Answer (score 3):

Without changing the type of `my_vec`, you could simply use access by indexing and [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut):

```
for index in 0..my_vec.len() {
    let (first, second) = my_vec.split_at_mut(index);

    first[some_index].push(second[0]);
}
```

*Note: beware, the indices in `second` are off by `index`.*

This is safe, relatively easy, and very flexible. It does not, however, work with iterator adaptors.